# implementing custom logic for phoneauth signup in my react-native firebase project

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to make a custom logic for signup `phoneauth` with Firebase that reads phone number from Firestore. If already present it shows **"Already exist else register a new account"**. But while implementing I am getting errors like if and else both are executed or multiple documents are created while registering.
Help me with it or refer to any other article will be a great help.

```
const onRegisterPress = () => {
     firestore().collection('InternData').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
       querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
           if(`${doc.data().phoneNumber}` == phoneNumber)
            return alert('Already registered. Try to login first')
         else{
           firestore()
           .collection('InternData')
           .add({
             phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
             fullName: fullName,
             date: date,
             expertiseIn: expertiseIn
           }).then(() => {
             // navigation.navigate('InternInfo')
             console.log('otp screen')
             onSubmit(phoneNumber)
           })
         }
       })
     })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query `firestore().collection('InternData').get()` would fetch all the documents and check each document if the `phoneNumber` exists on it causing you to execute your conditions multiple times to each documents found on the `InternData` collection.

For your use-case, I would suggest using the `where()` method instead. The query should be like this:

```
firestore()
.collection('InternData')
.where('phoneNumber', '==', phoneNumber)
.get()
```

The query above will fetch all the documents that match the value of the fieldname: "phoneNumber" with the value of the variable `phoneNumber`.

For reference, here's a full sample code:

```
firestore()
.collection('InternData')
.where('phoneNumber', '==', phoneNumber)
.get()
.then((querySnapshot) => {
    // If no match is found, create a new document to the collection.
    if (querySnapshot.empty) {        
        firestore()
        .collection('InternData')
        .add({
            phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
            fullName: fullName,
            date: date,
            expertiseIn: expertiseIn
        }).then(() => {
            // navigation.navigate('InternInfo')
            console.log('otp screen')
            onSubmit(phoneNumber)
        })
    } else {
        // This will trigger if there's a result for your query.
        return alert('Already registered. Try to login first')
    }
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});
```

---

For more information, you may check out this documentations:

- [Simple Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries)
- [Execute a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query)